# python subprocess performance analysis

Tags: python, performance-testing, psutil

I want to get the CPU and memory usage of a subprocess for performances analysis.
 I write this code, but I don't know if the information in my output is necessary and sufficient...

```
import psutil
import time
import subprocess
cmd = "python myScript.py" # for example
start_time = time.time()
proc = psutil.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
psProc = psutil.Process(proc.pid)
cpuTime = []
memoryPercent = []
while proc.poll() == None:
    cpuTime.append(psProc.cpu_times())
    memoryPercent.append(psProc.memory_percent())
    time.sleep(1)
execTime = str(time.time() - start_time)
print "\n".join(["execution total time " + execTime, str(max(cpuTime)), "max memory Percent " + str(max(memoryPercent)), "moy memory Percent " + str(sum(memoryPercent)/len(memoryPercent))])
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: We can't say if it is necessary and sufficient, since you did not tell us what would be necessary and sufficient for you.

Comment: I want to know if my software will maintain its performance over versions. If this information is the right criteria. If there are other important criterion (just for memory and cpu, not i/o)